# C# seeking for a library to help generate video showing text

Tags: windows, video, c#, mp4

I want to make a software in C# with this feature:

- There is a multiLine text box where user inputs string with N lines.
- The software outputs a MP4 video lasting N seconds.
- Each second the video has a text displayed according to the user input line.

Is there any library that can help doing this?

**The video is generated. With the text at the center, and the background remaining black.**

Comment: You are asking for several things at once (too broad). It is also not clear: does the software *generate* the video, or just play an existing one? Where does the text appear: do you want it embedded in the video, overlayed on the video, ...? Please [edit] the question.

Comment: @jan The video is generated by the software. With the text at the center, and the background remaining black. I am just questioning if anyone can show a library to do this.

Comment: Is there a difference between this video and something like a powerpoint slide show? I mean will you want audio? If not you might have more luck looking for a slideshow type tool/library.

Comment: okay. doing this really can be East in PowerPoint but what I want is to know the way to generate video by C sharp programmatically and this video is just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a C# demo that does something very similar in the [LEADTOOLS Multimedia SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/multimedia). (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor of this toolkit).

The SDK has a free evaluation that includes the demo, [which you can download here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads?category=mm).

After you install the SDK, you can find the demo’s source code in this folder:
[LEADTOOLS folder]\Examples\Multimedia\ltmm\Dotnet\CS\GenerateAVI

Since the demo generates AVI instead of MP4, and writes text on a blue background instead of black, you need to modify 6 lines of code in 4 functions to make it match your stated requirements. Below are all the changes needed:

In MainForm_Load()

```
//original code: _tbFile.Text = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\count.avi"; 
_tbFile.Text = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) + @"\text.mp4";
```

In _btnGenerate_Click()

```
//original code: double AvgTimePerFrame = (10000000 / 15);
double fps = 1.0; //1 frame per second
double AvgTimePerFrame = (10000000 / fps);
...
//original code: convertCtrl.VideoCompressors.MCmpMJpeg.Selected = true;
convertCtrl.TargetFormat = TargetFormatType.ISO;
convertCtrl.VideoCompressors.H264.Selected = true;
...
//original code: DrawCenteredText(i.ToString());
string s = "This is string number " + i.ToString();
DrawCenteredText(s);
```

In FillImage()

```
//original code: _blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
_blueBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);
```

In DrawCenteredText()

```
//original code:  using(Font f = new Font("Arial", 100))
//font was large since text was only a number
//make font smaller to fit larger text
using (Font f = new Font("Arial", 12))
```

The toolkit has free technical support during evaluation, so if you face problems getting the code to work, you can email the details to our support team.